# How to find which constraint is violated from pyomo's ipopt interface?

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I am running an optimization problem using pyomo's `ipopt` solver.  My problem is sort of complicated, and it is declared `infeasible` by IPOPT.  I will not post the entire problem unless needed.  But, one thing to note is, I *am* providing a warm start for the problem, which I thought would help prevent infeasibility from rearing its ugly head.

Here's the output from `pyomo` and `ipopt` when I set `tee=True` inside of the solver:

```
Ipopt 3.12.4: 

******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.12.4, running with linear solver mumps.
NOTE: Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:      104
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:       57

Total number of variables............................:       31
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:       29
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  0.0000000e+00 1.00e+01 1.00e+02  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
WARNING: Problem in step computation; switching to emergency mode.
   1r 0.0000000e+00 1.00e+01 9.99e+02   1.0 0.00e+00  20.0 0.00e+00 0.00e+00R  1
WARNING: Problem in step computation; switching to emergency mode.
Restoration phase is called at point that is almost feasible,
  with constraint violation 0.000000e+00. Abort.
Restoration phase in the restoration phase failed.

Number of Iterations....: 1

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   9.9999999999999986e+01    6.0938999999999976e+02
Constraint violation....:   1.0000000000000000e+01    1.0000000000000000e+01
Complementarity.........:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Overall NLP error.......:   9.9999999999999986e+01    6.0938999999999976e+02


Number of objective function evaluations             = 2
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 2
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 2
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 2
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 2
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.008
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.000

EXIT: Restoration Failed!


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 model, tee=True)
          4 

/Library/<path to solvers.pyc> in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    616                         result,
    617                         select=self._select_index,
--> 618                         default_variable_value=self._default_variable_value)
    619                     result._smap_id = None
    620                     result.solution.clear()

/Library/Frameworks<path to>/PyomoModel.pyc in load_from(self, results, allow_consistent_values_for_fixed_vars, comparison_tolerance_for_fixed_vars, ignore_invalid_labels, id, delete_symbol_map, clear, default_variable_value, select, ignore_fixed_vars)
    239             else:
    240                raise ValueError("Cannot load a SolverResults object "
--> 241                                 "with bad status: %s" % str(results.solver.status))
    242         if clear:
    243             #

ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error
```

You can actually see from the log outputted above, that there were only 2 constraint evaluates from this line:

```
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 2
```

So, it actually was declared infeasible pretty quickly, so I imagine it won't be difficult to figure out which constraint was violated.

How do I find out which constraint was violated?  Or which constraint is making it infeasible?

Here is a different question, but one that still is informative about `IPOPT`: [IPOPT options for reducing constraint violation after fewer iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850427/ipopt-options-for-reducing-constraint-violation-after-fewer-iterations)

Comment: I know that in theory one can use the dual + resolution theorem + complementary slackness to find out which constraint was violated.

Answer (score 1):

Running Ipopt with option print_level set to 8
gives me output like

```
DenseVector "modified d_L scaled" with 1 elements:
modified d_L scaled[    1]= 2.4999999750000001e+01
DenseVector "modified d_U scaled" with 0 elements:
...
DenseVector "curr_c" with 1 elements:
curr_c[    1]= 7.1997853012817359e-08
DenseVector "curr_d" with 1 elements:
curr_d[    1]= 2.4999999473733212e+01
DenseVector "curr_d - curr_s" with 1 elements:
curr_d - curr_s[    1]=-2.8774855209690031e-07
```

curr_c are the activity of equality constraints (seen as c(x)=0 internally for Ipopt), curr_d are the activites of inequality constraints (seen as d_L <= d(x) <= d_U internally).
So absolute values of curr_c are violations of equality constraints and max(d_L-curr_d,curr_d-d_U,0) are violations of inequality constraints.

The last iterate including constraint activites is also returned by Ipopt and may be passed back to Pyomo, so you can just compare these values with the left- and right-hand-side of your constraints.